# How can I set the locale for the current request in Quarkus

Tags: request, locale, quarkus

Quarkus sets the locale for the current request from the Accept-Language header.
I would like to override this behavior setting the locale from a cookie or maybe from a query parameter, maybe through by a filter or a provider.

Comment: The locale for what exactly?

Comment: @geoand, for everything Quarkus should use it: for Qute (template and message bundle), for Hibernate Validator, for Java Properties Bundles, but these are only examples.

Comment: For posterity, this is being traced in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33710